# Verify RSA sign with 512 bit public key in C#

Tags: c#, rsa

I used following code to convert X.509 public key to C# `RSAParameters` which works good with 1024 bits key. But for 512 bits key, `rsa.VerifyData(data, new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider(), sign)` return false.

I had verified sign, data with the public key in Java it's correct.

```
byte[] keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKeyString);

byte[] modulus;
switch (keyBytes.Length)
{
    case 94: // 512 bits
        modulus = new byte[65];
        Array.Copy(keyBytes, 24, modulus, 0, modulus.Length);
        break;
    case 162: // 1024 bits
        modulus = new byte[128];
        Array.Copy(keyBytes, 29, modulus, 0, modulus.Length);
        break;
    default:
        throw new NotSupportedException();
}

byte[] publicExponent = new byte[3];
Array.Copy(keyBytes, keyBytes.Length - 3, publicExponent, 0, 3);

var para = new RSAParameters();
para.Modulus = modulus;
para.Exponent = publicExponent;

...
```

And also, this unit test had passed:

```
byte[] modulus = new byte[65];
Array.Copy(keyBytes, 24, modulus, 0, modulus.Length);
Array.Reverse(modulus); // big-endian
if ((modulus[modulus.Length - 1] & 0x80) > 0) // make sure positive 
{
    var temp = new byte[modulus.Length];
    Array.Copy(modulus, temp, modulus.Length);
    modulus = new byte[temp.Length + 1];
    Array.Copy(temp, modulus, temp.Length);
}
var mFromByte = new BigInteger(modulus);
var mFromStr = BigInteger.Parse("10446137350258867541972982874422299386188841602828508348451210482770166585987014109048441013963536226102851240621532747362919294772011580690442657343607779"); // <- modulus output by java

Assert.AreEqual(0, mFromByte.CompareTo(mFromStr));
```

Comment: Why are you using `modulus = new byte[65];` in the 512 bit case? 65 bytes == 520 bits.

Comment: @Iridium, you're right! Thanks! I didn't really understand the X509 format, this is [public key](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8sow021frt5mp31/%E5%85%AC%E9%92%A5%E6%A0%BC%E5%BC%8F%E5%88%86%E6%9E%90.txt?dl=0), I thought the LEN "01000001" at line 24 means after 65 bytes are all need. (Sorry for Chinese of this file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Iridium's correction, Of course the 512 bits modulus should be 512 bits. I change code like this and `verify` returns true.

```
case 94:
    modulus = new byte[64];
    Array.Copy(keyBytes, 25, modulus, 0, modulus.Length);
    break;
```

In the binary of public key, the line 24 described modulus was after 65 bits, but the 0 at line 25 just a flag.

```
24  01000001    LEN(short format, 65 bits)
25  00000000
```